# MongoDb php extension not loading

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I'm trying to load the MongoDb extension for php on a Windows 7 64 bit PC, running XAMPP with Apache 2.0 and PHP 5.3.5, compiler version VC6. I started out with [this tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/webdev-with-mongodb-part3/), and have also tried the extensions that the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) suggested. MongoDb itself is running fine, and shell commands seem to work.

At the moment I have:

1. Added `extension=php_mongo.dll` to my `php.ini` file.
2. Put the VC6 version of `php_mongo.dll` (from the following [download page](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html), suggested by the PHP documentation) in the php/ext folder.
3. Restarted my Apache server.

I have also tried `php_mongo.dll` files form [Stealth's github](https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads), but they didn't seem to work either.

When restarting Apache, I don't get any errors, but I can't find anything on MongoDb in `phpinfo()`, and the Mongo class is not recognised either.

Any ideas of what might be wrong? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you tell us what extension folder php has registered within the phpinfo() output?

Comment: The extension folder is C:\xampp\php\ext

Comment: Which INI file did you modify? And which INI file does phpinfo() tell you it is using?

PHP will raise error messages when it cannot load an extension you have specified in the used php.ini file, so you are either suppressing these errors or you are modifying the wrong php.ini

Comment: I had this same problem, turns out I was enable the extension in wrong ini file, check your phpinfo for which php .ini file is being used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be incorrect version of extension. Try different versions downloaded from here: http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.4/windows

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bitnami WAMP Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) instead of XAMPP it comes preloaded `php_mongo.dll` driver installed and no need to configure `php.ini` file

There is no official MongoDB Driver released for PHP7. So it would be better to download the recommended PHP version  5.5.30(currently) offered by Bitnami Wamp Stack.

Answer (score 1):

There might be two reasons:

First one is as @Sadd suggested. Your mongodb extension should be loaded after what you have done so its very likely that you have enabled extension in wrong file. And yes, there are two such similar files (named `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` on windows computers), so make sure to enable it in `php.ini` file and run the following code `echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";` and you should see `loaded` on screen.

If you still don't see it, then the second thing you can do is to check whether the version is right or not. You can check your `phpinfo()` for your php version and then put the right versioned dll file in ext folder. In this, you can have to check whether your php is ts or nts and second one is whether your php is x64 or x86. I hope you are good to go after one or both of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving my crazy until I looked closely at my PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:23:59) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
```

Notice that it says **PHP 7.4.1** and **NTS** and **x64**?  This means that when I download from PECL, I need version **7.4 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64** or it won't run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the correct version of module is not added, an error is thrown.

[PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mongodb.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0]

When downloading the dll extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb, make sure that NTS (Non Thread Safe) or TS (Thread Safe) is chosen according to what shown from php -v command.

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 21:45:53) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
```

Although here it shows ZTS, TS version can be used in this case.